# Help finding an example of open set containing a closed set whose preimage is not contained in any open set containing preimage of the closed set

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous function between topological spaces $X$ and $Y$. If $X$ is not compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. Let $A$ be a closed subset of $Y$ and $U$ is an open set of $X$ containing $f^{-1}(A)$. I'm looking for an example that there's no open set $V$ containing $A$ such that $f^{-1}(V)$ is contained in $U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property

$$\forall A \subseteq Y: \forall U \in \tau_X: (f^{-1}[A] \subseteq U) \implies \left(\exists V \in \tau_Y: A \subseteq V \land f^{-1}[V] \subseteq U\right)$$

is well-known (it's in Engelking, e.g. and often formulated only for singleton sets $A$, which is sufficient for all $A$) to be equivalent to $f$ being a closed map.

So it suffices to take $f$ to be a continuous non-closed map, like the projection $\pi_1: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, e.g.

And more concretely still, let $A= \{0\}$, $U = \{(x,y): |y| < 1 \land |x| < 1 \text{ or } |y| \ge 1 \land |x|< \frac{1}{y}\}$ (the $x$-axis is aproximated by two assymptotes for large values of $y$.)
Then no neighbourhood $V$ of $0$ obeys $\pi^{-1}[V] = V \times \Bbb R \subseteq U$.

Comment: I just thought of an example similar to this one, take the same projection map, and let $W = \{(x, y)\vert xy = 1\}$ and $A = \{0\}$, $U = \mathbb{R}^2 - W$.

Comment: @nico23 Yes, that's a bit simpler, same idea. Nice.